# Can Telegram bot detect a new member joining a channel?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

**Can Telegram bot detect a new member joining a channel event?**

I have a Telegram bot and I set this bot as admin of a channel. I need to get the user id who joined to the channel and send me a private message with user details. is this possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the python implementation, but I can provide some information based on the [official HTTP-based specification](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).

In order to listen for a member joining a channel, you would [listen for `Updates`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates) of type `chat_member`. Each one will provide two values of [`ChatMember`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmember), one representing the user before s/he joined the chat and one for afterwards.

At this point, the API is not clearly worded, unfortunately, but you can simply do some tests. I assume that if the member object for 'before' has [`status = "left"`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberleft), then this user just joined the chat.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

Offical link: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberupdated

```
import telebot
from telebot.util import update_types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("your bot token here")

@bot.chat_member_handler()
def memberUpdated1(updated):
    print('chat_member_handler -----> ', updated)

bot.infinity_polling(allowed_updates=update_types)
```

Note: You need add bot to your channel and set it to admin!